# PGSQL - Change all columns of a specific datatype to text

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes, alter

I'm trying to change all the USER-DEFINED columns to TEXT in a specific ***view*** using pgsql.
Is it possible to do that in a single alter table query ou do I need to check first what columns contain that dataype and then perform the dataype change one by one?

This is what I'm trying:

```
ALTER TABLE if exists "schemaName"."Table_A"
ALTER COLUMN (
select column_name 
from information_schema.columns inf
where table_name = 'Table_A' and inf.data_type = 'USER-DEFINED') 
TYPE TEXT;
```

I'm getting and error in the subquery start "("

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this one by one. Generally speaking such DDL statements cannot work on several objects in one statement.

For ALTER TABLE, see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-altertable.html.

FOR ALTER VIEW, see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterview.html

Comment: Had to edit the question. I need to change x view column datatypes